# How can I make visual studio highlight .php files

Tags: php, visual-studio

Hope the title explains it all, but all I'm trying to do is open some .php files in my web-site solution and have Visual studio treat them as if they are html files. I don't need the actual PHJP code highlighted (it's only includes). The HTML syntax should be parse-able, should it not?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can also install the PHP Tools for Visual Studio add-in. Tools > Extension and Updates and then search for PHP online. Your first result should be this add-in.

If not, you can get it from here:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6eb51f05-ef01-4513-ac83-4c5f50c95fb5

Comment: It should be noted that this is not a free product.

Answer (score 58):

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> File Extension

in the Extension box, put .php. For the Editor, you can select HTML Editor. Click Add, then OK

Answer (score 6):

If you want intellisense, debug, and other advanced functionality, you could get the  [php ide for VS](http://www.jcxsoftware.com/vs.php)

If all you need is syntax highlighting, check out [this](http://blog.cumps.be/visual-studio-2008-and-php-coloring/) link. It's what I'm currently using, but doesn't have all the goodies of vs.php.

Answer (score 4):

Install [Phalanger](http://www.codeplex.com/Phalanger).

Answer (score 3):

If you're using VS2013 or older, I would recommend this extension for PHP Language support : https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2a10ba81-26c5-47d9-939b-6bcc7bbec251

For me [Josh's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196253/how-can-i-make-visual-studio-highlight-php-files/1196319#1196319) didn't work and [Miguel's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196253/how-can-i-make-visual-studio-highlight-php-files/15723842#15723842) needs PHP Tools which is free for 30 days but then you need to activate it.